# Orthogonality of Eigen vectors for the summation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a matrix, let's say $A$, can be decomposed into $A_1$ and $A_2$, and the eigenvectors of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are orthogonal. Does it guarantees that the Eigenvectors of $A$ would also be orthogonal?

Comment: So $A=A_1+A_2$ in this decomposition?

Comment: Yes. A is the summation of A1 and A2